# Unity Mathf.clamp not working as expected?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a first person shooter game and I want to limit the camera rotation. I have used Math.clamp to clamp the angle but after angle reaches to 0 it clamps to maximum angle. It was supposed to not clamp until -24f. How can I fix that.

```
 public void CameraRotate(Vector3 camrotate){

cam.transform.Rotate (camrotate*Time.deltatime);
        temporaryangle = cam.transform.eulerAngles;
        temporaryangle= new Vector3 (Mathf.Clamp(cam.transform.eulerAngles.x,-24f,55f),cam.transform.eulerAngles.y,cam.transform.eulerAngles.z); // camrotate means a vector and cam is the camera
        cam.transform.eulerAngles= temporaryangle;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have to use `camrotate.x` and not `camrotate.y`?

Comment: @Hristo y is used for left/right rotation. So I dont want limit on it

Comment: Oh I see, you are using `cam.transform.position`, but instead you probably want `cam.transform.rotation`?

Comment: @Hrist Sorry I copied wrong code. This is the final one

Comment: @Hrist See if you can help. Sorry for my previous code

Comment: No problem, can you please specify what the script is attached to?

Comment: @Hristo To a Camera Transform which is the child of the player

Comment: @Hristo only problem is it is behaving well at maximum value but when my camera euler rotation is less than 0 it changes to 55. It was not supposed to do that till euler rotation is less than -24f

Comment: @Hristo from google searh I found that euler rotation cant be negative. So  what do you think about it. I dont know any small alternative way for it. My code is already too long

Comment: could you replace `eulerAngles` with `rotation` everywhere in your code?

Comment: @Hristo Rotation needs a Quaternion. And I am fine with vectos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the comparison to a range that doesn't involve the wrap around at 0 / 360, by adding an offset before the comparison (let's say 180f), and removing it after:

```
var tmpOffset = 180f;

var clampedX = cam.transform.eulerAngles.x + tmpOffset;
clampedX = Mathf.Clamp(clampedX, tmpOffset - 24f, tmpOffset + 55f);
clampedX -= tmpOffset; // return to the correct value

temporaryangle = new Vector3 (clampedX, cam.transform.eulerAngles.y, cam.transform.eulerAngles.z); // camrotate means a vector and cam is the camera
```

Comment: FYI the reason it jumps to 55f when the rotation goes below 0 is Unity will map a negative value of -1 to 359 degrees etc, which of course is greater than your maximum of 55f, so will clamp it down to that.